# MySQL update with multiple variable in set

Tags: python, mysql

Well, I have a dictionary as input, ex:{'date':2020}.

And the key is the column name of the table, I just wanted to update the value into the table

```
string = ["{} = '{}'".format(k,v) for k,v in parameter_dict.items()]
string_joined =", ".join(string)
query = "UPDATE experiment SET" + string_joined + ' ' + 'WHERE ID =' + str(experimentID)
cursor.execute(query)
```

Above code  causes error

`_mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'Mar-2020-16_25_18', training_minutes = '0' WHERE ID =21' at line 1`

---

```
"UPDATE experiment SET %s WHERE ID =%s", (string_joined, experimentID)
```

Using above statement causes same error too

`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date_end = \'Mar-2020-16_18_52\', training_minutes = \'0\'' WHERE ID = 20' at line 1`

Also tried putting a single update into a for loop, but that causes another error!

So How can I solve this? Does it really can't send variables into the SET partition ? Thanks

Comment: You can't put column names into statement parameters. So you could write `SET mycolumn = %s` but not `SET %s`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to set my column names as variable too here

Comment: Well you can use something like your first option, where you glue the column names directly into the query. If you print out `query` after you've constructed it, you might be able to see where you've made an error.

Comment: Missed a blank after SET, thanks for your time @khelwood